# R - import csv columns and rows not showing propely

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to import some google analytics data in to R. But all I'm getting are rows. with x......

Has anyone ever experienced this and/or know the solution?

The code is simply:

```
TammysData <- read.csv("/Users/tammy/Desktop/Re3.csv", header = TRUE)
TammysData
```

Comment: You should upload a pic of the data that you're trying to load in and maybe the head of the data so we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/go3not

Comment: Have you tried to open your CSV as plain text file and see what separators it uses?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a CSV file, have you tried `readLines`?